# Sending bytes to contract from web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

so I have the following function in my smart contract:

```
 function proxy(address target, uint value, string memory signature, bytes memory data, uint eta) public returns (bytes32) {

        callData = data;
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = target.call.value(value)(callData);
        ...
    }
```

This function is just a proxy that calls another function in another smart contract, that function accepts many parameters.

This is my web3

```
 const txHash = await timelockContract.methods.proxy("0xF759Deb538aeEe26842b2cf37a9eB5A3687f8f23",
    0,
    "otherFunctionInOtherSmartContractfunctionCall(uint256, uint256)",
    BYTES PARAMETERS,
    1618335100
    ).send({from: "0x8077931197c1F0a1047c1d066d937931EAB4C5Dd"});
```

So, where 'BYTES PARAMETERS' is, goes the parameters for the function, so I have to send 2 parameters as bytes, but I dont find a way, from what I've read, you can convert to bytes using the following function:

`web3.utils.asciiToHex()`

But how can I send two parameters or more as bytes?